# load more with jQuery (no AJAX/PHP)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Faking a load more with jQuery (no AJAX/PHP) works great , but what i would like to know is:
Is there a way to instead of hiding the .item class load in the .item onclick so that the data isn't all loaded even if its hidden. so instead of .hide its .load or something. My knowledge is limited. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean `so that the data isn't all loaded even if its hidden`?

Comment: Show some code with what you've got so far. From what you've said, I guess you'd like to create elements on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 approaches:

1) Load all the data that you need, hide using CSS and then show on interaction according to requirements.

2) Second option is to make an AJAX call.

Both options are pretty common, depends what exactly your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript and simple HTML.

```
<script language="javascript">
function show(more){if(document.getElementById(more).style.display == 'none'){document.getElementById(more).style.display = 'block';}else{document.getElementById(more).style.display = 'none';}}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p>Display Text <br/>
<a onclick="show('more');" title="Read More" href="#">Load More</a>
<div id="more" style="display: none">Hidden Text</div></p>
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/SJAQh/